# Retrieve picture from an url

Tags: .net, ajax, image

On my ASP.Net page in C#, the user is able to enter an URL (web page). When it's done, I would want to get the picture in this page. For an example of this, go on Facebook and write a status with an URL in it. A panel open with the description of the page AND the picture.

Is there a parser or a little application that I can use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this post for code on [how to retrieve html DOM from an url](http://vaibhavgaikwad.wordpress.com/2007/01/05/getting-html-dom-from-url/) . Once you get a reference to the IHTMLDocument3 instance, use the [getElementsByTagName method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752545(VS.85).aspx) to retrieve
all IMG tags, and take the first.

Comment: Eum... I believe it's my question who's not clear but I want to get the first picture from the page (url). So, for example,if the user enter this url: http://www.monkeylinx.com/ViewPost.aspx?post=43, he will get the image with the man on the left... Facebook do that when you write and url...

Comment: Understand, I'll edit my answer: you have to read the DOM model of the page entered and seek for first IMG node.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was searching for!